# Why does iPhone text not suggest an American flag emoji?

Tags: keyboard, emoji

When typing out country names for example Canada, Russia, Mexico, Cuba, and China and all other country names I have tried using my iPhone with iOS 10 emojis are suggested with the respective flag for the country name I have just typed. When I type "America" this is not the case, why does typing the word America not suggest the use of the American flag emoji like so for all other countries?

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7664026?start=0&tstart=0) and [this](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/08/fix-predictive-emoji-not-working-ios-10-keyboard-iphone-ipad.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple is just being strict about America not being a country, but a continent. If you type **USA** or **United States**, predictive text will suggest the American flag:

[image: American Flag Suggestion]

Comment: You're right, i tried "United States of America" and "United States" which also both work.